# React Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, server

I have PostsSlice which provides data from server about posts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQxRd.png)

PostSlice Code:

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
};

const post = createSlice({
  name: "post",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getPosts(state, action) {
      state.posts = action.payload.posts;
    },
  },
});

const { getPosts } = post.actions;

export function GetPostByInterests() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await API.get("/posts", {
        params: {
          limit: 10,
          offset: 0,
        },
      });
      const data = response.data;
      const posts = data.data;

      dispatch(
        getPosts({
          posts: posts,
        })
      );
    } catch (e) {}
  };
}
```

I'm trying to pull out the user's image in the frontend in the post card and I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: posts.author.avatar is undefined

FrontEnd Code

```
export const News = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.post.posts);
 
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    dispatch(GetPostByInterests());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container-md shadow-lg bg-white py-10 px-8 mx-[5rem] my-[1rem] rounded-md">
      {posts.map((posts) => (
        <PostCard key={posts.id} posts={posts} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

PostCard FrontEnd image display:

```
        <img
          className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full object-cover mr-4 shadow"
          src={posts.author.avatar.url}
          alt="avatar"
        ></img>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcom to Stackoverflow @memphis

You need to use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in the `src` of the `img` tag. Like this:

```
<img
  className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full object-cover mr-4 shadow"
  src={posts?.author.avatar.url}
  alt="avatar"
></img>
```

It's also good practice to use a [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) when mapping through the data that is coming from the API, in order to avoid getting undefined errors when the data is being fetched:

```
// If posts aren't loaded yet, show a message
// (Or you can even show a loading spinner)
{!posts?.length ? <p>Nothing to Show</p> : posts.map((posts) => (
  <PostCard key={posts.id} posts={posts} />
))}
```

Comment: thank you very much, another probably stupid question, how to properly load data when using redux. 
what hooks are better to use UseEffect?

Comment: `{posts?.image.url ? (
<>
<img src={posts.image.url} alt="post image" />
</>
  ) : null}`
why this dont work???

Comment: @memphis For your first question, a good way of fetching data from an API is using `redux-thunk` and `extraReducers`. This way you can even handle their loading and error state more efficiently. You can learn more in hear: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#using-createasyncthunk

Comment: @memphis for your second question, what errors are you getting and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @memphis Moreover on your first question, the usage of hooks differs from scenario to scenario. I think in the code you've provided, using `useEffect` is much more suitable than `useLayoutEffect` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect ////// https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

Comment: I'm trying to get an image from a post if there is one. but I get the same undefined error

Comment: And one more stupid question how to do a redirect correctly after a successful request

Comment: @memphis Do this for the undefined image error and see if it helps: `<img src={posts?.image.url} alt="post image" />` //// It's not really necessary to have a ternary operator and check for it. (I don't know what the returned object looks like so if that doesn't work try this: `<img src={posts.image?.url} alt="post image" />`)

Comment: @memphis You can use `useNavigate` from `react-router`: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation

Comment: I am very grateful to you for your help, you can give a link to your Facebook or telegram page, I just can’t do the final work, and your answers are very helpful

Comment: You're most welcome but unfortunately, I cannot do that. Please accept the answer as the solution and upvote it if it solved the problem you were facing in your post.